# Auto-linkification of Tags.TagName fails when the tag name contains nonstandard characters

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, data-explorer, localization

Run the following SEDE query: https://data.stackexchange.com/japanese/query/178382.

All the tags except `kyūjitai-and-shinjitai`, `renyōkei`, `あれ`, and `たい-form` get auto-linkified. These happen to also be the only four tags that contain characters outside the standard set of allowed characters `[a-z 0-9 + # - .]`. It would be nice if these would auto-linkify too.

(I imagine this is even more applicable for other language sites like [Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) - if you [rerun the query for Russian](https://data.stackexchange.com/russian/query/178382), you find that well over half the tags don't linkify because they contain Cyrillic characters.)

Comment: We’ve reviewed this request and have moved it to our backlog. I’ve updated the status to status-deferred.

Comment: @V2Blast what does that mean in this case? No one has time to review my [Pull Request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/105) and merge it?

Comment: @rene: We're triaging the many [status-review] tagged items from 2020 and earlier, so that's just the guidance I was given. I'll check with the relevant dev team about this particular issue :)

Answer (score 6):

Now that the sites clearly support Unicode tags where appropriate, they should indeed be linkified like the rest.

Assuming no one has any issue with me [going a bit overboard](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/46) to address JavaScript's poor support for Unicode character classes in regular expressions, all of the mentioned tags will be linkified following a pull and redeploy of Data Explorer (some revision > 2014.5.7.25).

Comment: Please add `TagName` to the documentation of magic columns, while you're at it. And can you allow the title to be `Tag Link`, to be consistent with the others? And will this future version allow [Unicode in all autolinks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234912/please-support-unicode-in-automatic-links)? And can I have a unicorn?

Comment: It's [actually already mentioned](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) at the bottom. Allowing for `Tag Link` too is easy enough; the current options are based on the relevant fields you'd pull this information out of.

Comment: It's not fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I've opened a new  PR [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/105) where I now try to get a fix passed Nick that doesn't introduce a new library. The fix will only work for newer browsers (so IE11 will behave like it did) as it relies on RegExp Unicode support in the browser.

Allow for 6 to 8 weeks to get review feedback and another 6 to 8 weeks for merging and deploying.