# SEDE doesn't render links with non-standard characters

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, data-explorer, localization

I ran the query [Most common tags with missing wiki/excerpt](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/94917/most-common-tags-with-missing-wiki-excerpt) on Stack Overflow em Português and links with localized tag names containing non-standard characters aren't linking properly:

> [image: SEDE output, with links which contain non-standard characters showing as plain-text rather than as proper links]

Can this be fixed?

---

This bug is similar to, but not a duplicate of, this [other bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226703/auto-linkification-of-tags-tagname-fails-when-the-tag-name-contains-nonstandard) about non-standard characters causing *tags* to not render properly in SEDE:

> [image: Rendered tags in SEDE output; tags with non-standard characters render as plain text rather than as a proper tag]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-linkification of Tags.TagName fails when the tag name contains nonstandard characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226703/auto-linkification-of-tags-tagname-fails-when-the-tag-name-contains-nonstandard)

Comment: Although it's worth noting that contrary to the implications of my answer there I actually have to fix it a different way and have not yet done so (but Data Explorer is quite behind on deployed updates too :/)

Comment: Oh, actually again I guess this isn't strictly a duplicate since this is a separate area that doesn't properly handle the non-ASCII characters

Comment: @Tim thanks, vote retracted.

Comment: This is still broken, unfortunately: https://i.stack.imgur.com/muY4A.png