# SQL query used to calculate staff escalation statistics doesn't take into account different tag names for international sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, international-sites

This is a bug report of a SQL query used at [What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/341401).

In the above post, [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) posts are counted using this SEDE query: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1245452/posts-with-status-review-network-wide.

One of community members at ja.stackoverflow.com noticed that this query does not take moderator tags on international sites into account. Moderator tag names are localized on some international sites. For example, es.meta.stackoverflow.com uses [estado-en-revisión] rather than [status-review].

Here is a list of localized [status-review] tags I noticed (in the alphabetical order of site URLs):

- [estado-en-revisión] - [Meta Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/estado-en-revisi%c3%b3n/synonyms)
- [調査中] - [Meta Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad/synonyms)
- [status-revisão] - [Meta Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-revis%c3%a3o/synonyms)
- [статус-проверка] - [Meta Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0/synonyms) and [Russian Language in Russian Meta](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0/synonyms)

Would someone (possibly SE staff?) please update the query and calculate stats using the new query, at least from the next quarter?

Comment: Looking at the international sites [listed in the tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/international-sites/info), the tag (статус-проверка) exists on [rus.meta.se], too. In that case (status-review) is [a synonym](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0/synonyms) - similarly as on the sites that you listed in [the first revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/392727/1).

Comment: Can you help me with the OUTER APPLY part of the query, which aims to select the current status? In English, all those tags start with `status-` - what's the Japanese equivalent? Or should I just use a list of tags?

Comment: @Glorfindel I might have still missed some status tag on that site, but after [this modification](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1779511/posts-with-status-review-network-wide?fromDate=2023-04-22&tillDate=2023-06-15)  of the OUTER APPLY part I am getting something in the column which is supposed to be the current status tag. The current version [of your query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1245452/posts-with-status-review-network-wide?fromDate=2023-04-22&tillDate=2023-06-15) seems to have only status-completed.

Comment: @Glorfindel
Thank you for your quick response.
For future reference, I created a query to get a list of the translated names of the tags.
https://data.stackexchange.com/jame/query/1779534/get-localized-moderator-tag-status-names-by-synonyms

Comment: @Glorfindel 
Regarding the Japanese tag names, Martin's comment is correct.
Since these do not have a common string at the beginning, there is no way to smartly match them.

Comment: @mjy thank you, I've added those to the query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the report, I have updated the query and it now includes non-English sites:

[image]

(that the tags don't render is [another SEDE bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226703/295232))